# Word for the deterioration of cardboard on the line where it folds

Tags: word-request

What's the word for the mark that is left on a cardboard right where it is folded?

[image: fold line on cardboard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line or mark is known as the *[crease](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crease)*, as defined by ODO

> A line or ridge produced on paper or cloth by folding, pressing, or crushing:
>   *khaki trousers with knife-edge creases*

The word has a special meaning in lacrosse, hockey, cricket, and perhaps other sports, but it would be well-understood in reference to paper, cardboard, fabric, and other flat materials that can be folded.

Comment: Good answer. Also noting that crease is both **noun** and **verb**. *You made a crease in the cardboard by creasing the cardboard.*